# Ellipsized TextView with suffix

Tags: android, textview

I have text that may be ellipsized in two lines. But no matter how many lines it takes, I need that some additional (short but length may vary) text would ALWAYS be fully visible at the end of previous text.

Here are three cases representing my problem:

[image: Cases]

How can I achieve this? I tried measuring text length and splitting it into two TextViews but it's not accurate enough and also hits performance badly.

Comment: Hope [this](http://developer-android.blogspot.in/2012/08/get-number-of-lines-of-textview.html) will help you to get number of lines of textview.

Comment: But the more problematic (at least it seems to me) part is making ellipsizing stop not at the very end of the TextView